# Changing Windows CE 6.0 LOCALE using native code

Tags: windows-ce, locale

I am writing an C/C++ application for WinCE 6.0, which should let the user choose its regional settings like date, time, etc. Depending on actual user's LOCALE, GetDateFormat() and GetTimeFormat() functions result in well formatted strings. That is why I would like to change the Windows CE 6.0 LOCALE programmatically. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [NLS APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee491575%28v=WinEmbedded.60%29.aspx) - probably starting with [`SetUserDefaultLCID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ee491343%28v=winembedded.60%29.aspx).